# Find the max value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

My requirement is to find the greatest/max value in an array, which may contain other arrays within it. For example we could have a look at an array below.

```
$array =
    array(
        13,
        array(10, 4, 111, 3),
        4,
        array(23, 450, 12,array(110, 119, 20, 670), 45 ,45,67,89),
        );

$max = find_max($array, 0);

print "Maximumum Value is  $max";
```

I already have a working function find_max, but all I wanted to know is what could the **best and efficient** possible way to do this other than the code given below.

```
function find_max($array, $maxValue) {
    foreach ($array as $member) {
        if (is_array($member)) {
            $maxValue = find_max($member, $maxValue);
        } else {

            if($member==$maxValue){
                continue;
            }
            if ($member > $maxValue) {
                $maxValue = $member;
            }
        }
    }
    return $maxValue;
}
```

Comment: there is a "max" function which accepts also arrays, but i think it is only for 1 dimensional arrays, not sure: http://php.net/manual/de/function.max.php - on this page you will also find a solution for multi dimensional arrays in a comment.

Comment: I know of the max function, it would not work for this condition; if I am not wrong it would throw a notice 'Array to string conversion'. And regarding the comment I had already viewed and implemented it. I was looking if there are better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the max value requires O(n), so you can't improve it drastically, as far as I know.
But, you can add a minor improvement to your code:

```
function find_max($array, $maxValue) {
    foreach ($array as $member) {
        if (is_array($member)) {
            $maxValue = find_max($member, $maxValue);
        } else {
            if ($member > $maxValue) {
                $maxValue = $member;
            }
        }
    }
    return $maxValue;
}

$array =
array(
    13,
    array(10, 4, 111, 3),
    4,
    array(23, 450, 12,array(110, 119, 20, 670), 45 ,45,67,89),
    );
$ans = find_max($array, 0);
echo "ans = $ans";
```

**output:** 670

Answer (score 2):

You can't find the max of an array (or an array of arrays) faster than O(n) or [linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time).

If you need to constantly find the max of this array, I would recommend sorting the array or using a different (sorted) data structure all together if possible.

You could also keep a reference to the max and update it when you insert data. Obviously this assumes you are inserting the data yourself and not getting it from somewhere else, in which case my last comment is useless to you.

Answer (score 1):

Really, what you're doing would be the best way to search for a max in a multidimensional array. Utilizing recursion to find the depth and checking for the greater number. Sorry, there just isn't a built in function to do this.

This is some complicated way to sort a multidimensional array based on the inner most array, but it's a fairly involved concept. (searches for it).

usort might be of use?